# Shiv'a Vetish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 197 letters in the Torah's description of the first day of Creation ([Gen. 1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0101.htm):1-5).

([Nefesh Yosef](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6211&pgnum=12) - second to last line of the page. Curiously, a few lines earlier he says that the number of letters is 195.)

Comment: 197 by my count.

Comment: That's what I meant - first he says it's 195 (which seems to be incorrect), then 197.

Answer (score 2):

Hoshea has 197 Pesukim.

Answer (score 1):

Some give 197 as the number of attendees of the First Zionist Congress, though others differ.

Comment: See also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6277.